# Arithmetic-Harmonic Geometric-Harmonic or mean?

Tags: statistics, functions, means

There is a Arithmetic-Geometric Mean that appears to be common and very useful throughout several branches of math. Is there a Arithmetic-Harmonic Mean and a Geometric-Harmonic mean? What are their properties and are the useful? Is there a general f(x)-g(x) mean? What properties would that have.

Comment: Far as I recall, the A-H mean sequence converges to the geometric mean, and while the H-G mean is defined, it doesn't have any particularly nice properties (unlike the elliptic integral estimate offered by the A-G mean).

Note that $HG(x,y) = 1/AG(x^{-1}, y^{-1}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AHM is just the geometric mean. This is easy to see, after proving they have a common limit:
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n), \quad b_{n+1} = \frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n} = \frac{a_n b_n}{a_{n+1}}, $$
so $ a_{n+1}b_{n+1}=a_nb_n = \dotsb = a_0 b_0 $; the common limit is then $a_{\infty}^2=a_0 b_0$, so $a_{\infty}=b_{\infty}= \sqrt{a_0b_0} $.

Meanwhile, the HGM is simply related to the AGM: $HGM(a,b)=1/AGM(1/a,1/b)$ (a proof is found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1186443/221811)).

As for generalisations, there are loads. See for example [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37576/nth-order-generalizations-of-the-arithmetic-geometric-mean) MathOverflow post, and [this](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/papers/nate-thesis.pdf) writeup about the generalisation to some sort of algebraic geometry, with plenty of nice $\theta$-functions. Indeed, I would have thought that any iteration of a homogeneous function on the positive quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a contraction with respect to $\lvert x-y\rvert$ will give an analogous merged mean.